# Batch file command looper

Tags: windows, batch

Just a fun batch file I have made. I wanted an easy way to loop any arbitrary command several times: loopme.bat

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
echo LoopMe v1.0

IF "%~1"=="/?" (GOTO HELP)
IF "%~1"=="" (GOTO HELP)
IF "%2"=="" (SET TIMEOUT=1) ELSE (SET TIMEOUT=%2)
SET COMMAND=%~1
SET COUNTER=0

:RUN
SET /A COUNTER=%COUNTER% + 1
CMD /C "%COMMAND%"
echo.
echo Command  : "%COMMAND%"
echo Times run: %COUNTER%
CHOICE /C QC /N /T %TIMEOUT% /D C /M "Press Q to quit, otherwise wait %TIMEOUT% second(s) to run again."
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (GOTO EOF) ELSE (GOTO RUN)

:HELP
echo Perform the same command in a loop. 
echo Commands containing ^& or ^| must be escaped with ^^
echo Commands containing variables must be escaped with ^^ in the varible name
echo Optionally specify loop time. Default is 1 second.
echo.
echo Usage: loopme dir 2                             
echo               [run dir in current, loop 2 seconds]
echo.
echo        loopme "cls ^& netstat -an ^| find ".109""
echo               [clear screen then run netstat with find filter, loop 1 second]
echo.
echo        loopme "echo %%^time%%" 
echo               [display the time, loop 1 second]
echo
echo.

:EOF
```

Any improvements or suggestions?

p.s this is my new way to annoy colleagues who leave their workstation unlocked:

```
loopme "color %^time:~9,2% ^&echo. ^& echo. ^&echo. ^& echo YOU HAVE BEEN HACKED!! ^& echo. ^&echo."
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want an easy way to loop an arbitrary command several times...

```
set /a loop=100
for /L %%P in (1,1,%loop%) do (
    echo Looping for one hundred times
)
```

The first line is obvious.

The second line is a bit harder - `for /L` specifies that for every number in a certain set, the batch file will do something. `%%P` is a parameter that holds what number the `for` loop is at currently - it can be any letter you like (and some other characters but they are dangerous so stick with letters). `in (1,1,%loop%)` specifies that this is for every number from `1` to `%loop%`, increasing by `1` every time. `do ( ... )` obviously tells the batch file what it needs to do.

So, in every number from `1` to `100`, it will `echo` `Looping for one hundred times`. This will obviously scroll down the page seeing as we never clear the screen with `cls`.

Once a `for` loop has reached its final number, the batch file continues on executing the commands following the final `)` as you would expect.

I can expand this answer if you want to know what you're doing wrong and right in your own code example, but I pretty much just did the same thing in 4 lines which should suffice.

---

And here comes the expansion. Please note that your code is pretty close to perfect, and these tips only encourage good scripting habits.

To begin with, you spelt `variable` as `varible` in `line 3` of the `:HELP` label.

First line of the `:RUN` label:

```
set /a counter=%counter% + 1
```

Instead of this, one can do

```
set /a counter+=1
```

This isn't *incredibly* helpful at the moment, but when you want to add a variable to another variable...

```
set /a varA+=%varB%
```

This also works for other operators...

```
set /a varA*=%varB%
```

And slightly more complex equations...

```
set /a varA-=%varB% * %varC%
```

Which will evaluate `%varB% * %varC%`, then subtract the result from `varA`

The command `CMD /C "%COMMAND%"` is not entirely necessary to my knowledge - simply writing `%COMMAND%` on a new line will cause the batch parser to expand it, so if `%COMMAND%` is set as `exit`, the line will read, at run time, `exit`. This enables you to use this method rather than the entire `CMD /C` method.

Another concern that could become more than just a concern is your method for checking the `errorlevel` - there's a problem. Checking with quotes and `==` denotes a *string* comparison - *never* good when you're dealing with two numbers. So you'll need a fix for this problem, and luckily it's quite simple.

```
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 ( ... )
```

This tests for a mathematical equivalence - *always* good when you're dealing with two numbers. All the operators for mathematical equivalencies are...

```
EQU - 'equal to'
NEQ - 'not equal to'
GTR - 'greater than'
LSS - 'less than'
GEQ - 'greater than or equal to'
LEQ - 'less than or equal to'
```

And finally, using `if varA==varB (goto label)` is not necessary - it works just as well as `if varA==varB goto label`. The only time you need brackets is when you plan on conditionally executing multiple lines *or* if you need to use `else` (just to be safe). When using brackets, always remember to *balance* them. Indenting isn't required, but it gets *really* confusing when you start nesting `if` statements and `for` loops without it. An example of executing multiple lines...

```
if %varA% GTR %varB% (
    echo varB is less than varA
    if %varA% GTR %varC% (
        echo varC is less than varA
    ) else (
        echo varC is greater than varA
)
```

To conclude, your code obviously works fine, but some habits die hard in weird circumstances later on, so it's best to get used to using common conventions (they exist for a reason!). As a side note, remember that *batch scripting is not case sensitive*. Anything I wrote here, along with anything you wrote, can be written in the opposite case - it has no difference.

Comment: The best first posts are definitely answers. Exemplified here by you, blaizor. Welcome to CodeReview.